# UPI payment integration in ios

Tags: swift, payment, upi

I am trying to integrate UPI payment in my ios app.
I have seen some apps like, if we will select UPI payment it will display the list of UPI apps that are installed in the device. I need to implement a similar kind of feature in my ios app.

I have tried generating URL as specified in [NPCI doc](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/all/themes/npcl/images/PDF/UPI_Linking_Specs_ver_1.5.1.pdf)

I tried using `UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler` to open the UPI app. Every time it's opening WhatsApp only.

How can i select my favourite UPI payment app from the list of Installed apps on device for doing UPI payment

Comment: Please any body suggest me  how to solve

Comment: Did you find solution? if so please share the details